# Automatically assigning a value to a Guid

Tags: asp.net, guid

can we automatically assign a value on a Guid? like for example, i want this to be a value of my guid: "914aaa44-4e11-e311-96f7-d8d3855b1531"

is it even possible?

Comment: Have you actually tried `Guid guid = new Guid("914aaa44-4e11-e311-96f7-d8d3855b1531");` ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ff78dc.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want a new GUID every time use

```
Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
```

If you want a specific guid use (wrt your example)

```
Guid guid = new Guid("914aaa44-4e11-e311-96f7-d8d3855b1531");
```